# Не работает OnCollisionEnter Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть `player`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float forwardSpeed;
    public float rotateSpeed;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left")) {
            transform.Rotate(0, -rotateSpeed, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right")) {
            transform.Rotate(0, rotateSpeed, 0);
        }

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * forwardSpeed);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Obstacle")
        {
            Debug.Log("Do something here");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: alt]

Также есть `obstacle`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему то при касании игрока `obstacle` сообщение не появляется... Что я делаю не так?

Comment: По ссылке выше есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех твердых тел нужно накладывать компонент Rigidbody, а если вы уже и хотите его сделать неподвижным или еще что то, это редактируется непосредственно в Rigidbody